# Steps to follow to put an image from my laptop as background of a website

Tags: image, web, upload

I have jpg and png. I do not know what is the line to write to insert the image.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It seems that you are 16 steps away from even being able to ask this question.  Stack Overflow is for code specific issues and / or problems that can be [Reproduced](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  I would suggest first getting started on a basic [HTML Tutorial](https://html.com/) and subsequently get familiar with FTP or SFTP as a way to upload both images and HTML files.  If you hit a snag in that process and your **HTML doesn't work** .. Paste the disfunctional HTML here and we'll be able to help you!

Answer (score 0):

```
background-image: url( link to the image )
```

Comment: It does not work. Not writting mistake. But thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You better learn HTML and CSS properly or you can also just google search it `How to set website background image`.

**StackOverflow** is NOT for teaching you how to code, it's about solving your problems. Share your code if you have problems in/related your code, we'll try to help.

Comment: Thanks. I am learning it now. But still do not know. I Google what you said. Thanks